# Replace given index of a vector in a column by the values of the vector

Tags: r, indexing, replace, match

I am struggling with this supposedly simply task:

**updated df:**
I have this data frame:

```
df<- structure(list(Species = c("setosa", "not_setosa", "setosa", 
"setosa", "setosa", "setosa"), index = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))

     Species index
1     setosa     4
2 not_setosa     3
3     setosa     2
4     setosa     5
5     setosa     1
6     setosa     3
```

and this vector:

```
my_vector <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")

[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five"  "six"
```

**I would like to replace the values in the index column `df$index` with the values of the corresponding indices in the vector `my_vector`**

The expected output:

```
     Species index
1     setosa  four
2 not_setosa three
3     setosa   two
4     setosa  five
5     setosa   one
6     setosa three
```

I have tried many variations with `which` and `match` but did not come to an end. I also tried with factors but was not successful.

Comment: Check your data sample, your `dput`  is not your `data.frame`

Comment: `df$index = my_vector[df$index]`

Comment: have updated. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply index `my_vector` by the values in `df$index`.

```
df$index = my_vector[df$index]
```

Output:

```
     Species index
1     setosa  four
2 not_setosa three
3     setosa   two
4     setosa  five
5     setosa   one
6     setosa three
```

Input:

```
structure(list(Species = c("setosa", "not_setosa", "setosa", 
"setosa", "setosa", "setosa"), index = c("four", "three", "two", 
"five", "one", "three")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @thx. Pretty embarrassing, but I can't help sometimes I have these gaps. thank you very much!

Comment: @TarJae, imo no question is a bad question. And others like me can learn from your post too :)